# What's the difference between “?android:attr/” and “?attr/” in an Android layout XML file?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

What's the difference between `?android:attr/` and `?attr/` in an Android layout XML file?

Which one should we use in different situations?

Answer (score 20):

From *[Difference between “?attr/” and “?android:attr/” in Android](http://grishma102.blogspot.com/2015/02/difference-between-attr-and-androidattr.html)*:

> **1. ?attr/**
>
> Defines and refers to the value of an attribute which you have defined on your own in your application.
>
> **2. ?android:attr/**
>
> It refers to the values of an attribute which are already available in Android built-in. More specifically, the `?` implies an extra level of indirection. Think of it as de-referencing an attribute to fetch the resource it points to rather than referring to the attribute itself.

Comment: And do you by any chance know what's the difference between `?android:attr/` and `?android:`? For example, there are colors `?android:attr/textColorPrimary` and `?android:textColorPrimary`. Both seem to work in the same way, but I didn't dig into the themes and code to check for differences. Official documentation on these seem to be quite scarce.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#ReferencesToThemeAttributes    "Because the system resource tool knows that an attribute resource is expected in this context, you do not need to explicitly state the type (which would be ?android:attr/textColorSecondary)—you can exclude the attr type."

Comment: There isn't any original contribution here. And it doesn't really answer the first question. And certainly not the second (which is probably the real one). What *is* the (essential) difference? What is the gist of it?

Comment: Was it just the first search result that was pasted here?

Answer (score 1):

From *[Difference between “?attr/” and “?android:attr/” in Android](http://grishma102.blogspot.com/2015/02/difference-between-attr-and-androidattr.html)*:

> **?attr/**
>
> - Defines and refers to the value of an attribute which you have defined on your own in your application.
>
> **?android:attr/**
>
> - Refers to the values of an attribute which are already available in Android built-in.

Comment: There isn't any original contribution here. And it doesn't really answer the first question (based on the quote). And certainly not the second (which is probably the real one). What *is* the (essential) difference? What is the gist of it?